# Why does 2.10 insist on specifying type parameter bounds (worked fine in 2.9)?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scala-2.9

I have the following case class:

```
case class Alert[T <: Transport](destination: Destination[T], message: Message[T])
```

In Scala 2.9.2, the following method signature has compiled fine:

```
def send(notification: Alert[_]) {
  notification match {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now in Scala 2.10.1 it fails to compile with the following error:

```
type arguments [_$1] do not conform to class Alert's type parameter bounds [T <: code.notifications.Transport]
```

Why is this? How can I fix the error? Simply giving the same type bounds to `send` results in a lot more compile errors...

**Update:** Looking at [SIP-18](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/modularizing-language-features.html), I don't think the reason is that I don't have existential types enabled, as SIP-18 says it's only needed for non-wildcard types, which is exactly what I do have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There error seems to be saying that the existential type "`_`" is not constrained to be a subtype of `Transport`. This may be the preferred solution,

```
trait Transport
trait Destination[T]
trait Message[T]
case class Alert[T <: Transport](destination: Destination[T], message: Message[T])

def send[T <: Transport](notification: Alert[T]) {
  notification match {
    case _ => ()
  }
}
```

This also seems to work,

```
def send(notification: Alert[_ <: Transport])
```

but I think it's preferable not to use existential types.

Comment: I had already tried the first approach and it just caused more compiler errors, but the second one works for me.

Comment: As for not using existential types, what would you recommend instance?

Comment: I don't get any compilation errors with the first approach--maybe you need to include more code to make them appear?

Comment: Sorry, of course. I then get: `type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Seq[code.notifications.Alert[Product with Serializable with code.notifications.Transport]]
[error]  required: Seq[code.notifications.Alert[T]]
[error]   def toAlerts[T <: Transport]: Seq[Alert[T]] = subject.toSeq.flatMap(subject => {`

Comment: But yes, basically I try to follow the chain back and I keep getting these errors about `Product with Serializable with code.notifications.Transport` not matching `T`, where `T <: Transport`.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I can't reproduce your errors with the code you have posted. If you can post more code, then I could try to debug the errors.

Comment: Thanks, Kipton, I think it's easiest to just go with your solution for now.